# Segmentation fault when calling fgets

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to write a simple program to read data from files listed in a plain text list, but I keep running into a segmentation fault when I try to call fgets() in my processFile function.

It doesn't happen if I were to simply call something like processFile("file.txt"), but it happens when I try to call processFile through my processList function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void processFile (char *file)
{
    char line[256];
    FILE* pgmFile;
    pgmFile = fopen(file, "r");
    fgets(line, 200, pgmFile); // Seg fault here
    fclose(pgmFile);
}    

// Runs processFile on every file listed in list
void processList (char *list)
{
    FILE *pgmList;
    pgmList = fopen(list, "r");

    char line[256];

    while (fgets(line, 255, pgmList) != NULL) {
        processFile(line);
    }
    fclose(pgmList);
}      

int main ()
{
    processList("downgesture_test1.list");
}
```

Comment: Upon successful completion fopen(), fdopen() and freopen() return a FILE pointer.  Otherwise, NULL is returned and errno is set to indicate the error. Please check what fopen() returns. Life is not always perfect. Files may not be accessible.

Comment: Dude - error checking!  Make sure "fopen()" succeeded before you try to read from it ;)

Answer (score 4):

Try checking return value of `fopen`. What if it's `NULL`? Because it is likely that your "file name" has trailing `\n`.

Comment: This was the exact problem!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: And if you believe you already have such a security, consider checking that your test is indeed `pgmFile == NULL` and NOT `pgmFile = NULL` — might save you a fair amount of time.

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou, `!pgmFile` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

fopen will return NULL if the file doesn't exist.  Add some error handling after the call to fopen, it's possible you just have a bad entry in your list.

What may be happening is that pgmFile is NULL, and fgets tries to access it, causing the seg fault.